# Data file to xml using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I wish to convert a text data file to xml using regex.

This is some sample data I will use:

```
^JOB DMR344JAL -C01 -Z"PRT16"
^PAGE 01
^GLOBAL PAGELBL
Pag.
^$PAGE 01
^GLOBAL CMPADDR
COMPANY
Somestreet 1
10000 Somecity
^GLOBAL TELEPHONELBL
Telephone
^GLOBAL TELEPHONE
0000 0/000.00.00
^GLOBAL TELEFAXLBL
Fax
^GLOBAL TELEFAX
0000 0/000.00.00
^GLOBAL ORGNOLBL
Orig.nr.
^GLOBAL ORGNO
^GLOBAL WEBSITE
http://www.internet.com
^GLOBAL EMAIL
e-mail account@internet.com
^GLOBAL SEAT1LBL
Maatschappelijke zetel
^GLOBAL SEAT2LBL
Someaddress
^GLOBAL HANDREG
RPR
^GLOBAL HANDREGNR
Somecity
^GLOBAL TITLE
^GLOBAL TITLE1
FACTUUR
^GLOBAL INVNOLBL
```

The regex I got so far looks like this:

```
\^((?:GLOBAL|FIELD)\s(?:[A-Z0-9]+))\r
```

The replace regex looks like this:

```
<$1>$2</$1>
```

This gives me the following result:

```
^JOB DMR344JAL -C01 -Z"PRT16"
^PAGE 01
<GLOBAL PAGELBL>$2</GLOBAL PAGELBL>
Pag.
^$PAGE 01
<GLOBAL CMPADDR>$2</GLOBAL CMPADDR>
COMPANY
Somestreet 1
10000 Somecity
<GLOBAL TELEPHONELBL>$2</GLOBAL TELEPHONELBL>
Telephone
<GLOBAL TELEPHONE>$2</GLOBAL TELEPHONE>
0000 0/000.00.00
<GLOBAL TELEFAXLBL>$2</GLOBAL TELEFAXLBL>
Fax
<GLOBAL TELEFAX>$2</GLOBAL TELEFAX>
0000 0/000.00.00
<GLOBAL ORGNOLBL>$2</GLOBAL ORGNOLBL>
Orig.nr.
<GLOBAL ORGNO>$2</GLOBAL ORGNO>
<GLOBAL WEBSITE>$2</GLOBAL WEBSITE>
http://www.internet.com
<GLOBAL EMAIL>$2</GLOBAL EMAIL>
e-mail account@internet.com
<GLOBAL SEAT1LBL>$2</GLOBAL SEAT1LBL>
Maatschappelijke zetel
<GLOBAL SEAT2LBL>$2</GLOBAL SEAT2LBL>
Someaddress
<GLOBAL HANDREG>$2</GLOBAL HANDREG>
RPR
<GLOBAL HANDREGNR>$2</GLOBAL HANDREGNR>
Somecity
<GLOBAL TITLE>$2</GLOBAL TITLE>
<GLOBAL TITLE1>$2</GLOBAL TITLE1>
FACTUUR
^GLOBAL INVNOLBL
```

How on earth do i get the values between **$1**????

- Each field has ^ as indicator.
- The lines following the field will be used in **$2**.
- Don't mind the first 2 lines and the line with $PAGE 01.
  (I will split the file before applying regex)

I've been breaking my head over this for some time and I would be very grateful if
anyone with more regex experience could help me out or point me in the right direction!

Kind regards,

Stanny

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `^` in your regex to match a `^` as it indicates the beginning of the string in regex.

I think the required regex is `\^(GLOBAL|FIELD)\s([A-Z0-9]+)` which matches **GLOBAL** or **FIELD** followed by a whitespace followed by sequence of uppercase letters or digits of any length (at least one). Replace the matches with `<$1>$2</$1>`

Comment: Thank you Naveed but I allready got that part :)
(look between the two code blocks in my question)

I need the part between those matches to use as $2

Comment: I didn't get the question well. What should be output for

    `^GLOBAL PAGELBL

    Pag.
    ^$PAGE 01
    ^GLOBAL CMPADDR
    COMPANY
    Somestreet 1
    10000 Somecity`

Comment: output should be:

<GLOBAL_PAGELBL>Pag.</GLOBAL_PAGELBL>
<GLOBAL_CMPADDR>Somestreet 1 10000 Somecity</GLOBAL_CMPADDR>

Answer (score 1):

If  i got you right..this is what you are looking for

Regex:`"\\^(GLOBAL.*?)(?=[\n\r]+)(.*?)(?=\\^|$)"`

To be more general you can use `"\\^(.*?)(?=[\n\r]+)(.*?)(?=\\^|$)"`

Replace:`<$1><$2></$1>`

Use it with **singleline** option

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
((GLOBAL|FIELD)\s([A-Z0-9]+))(.+?)(?=\^)\^
```

Replace:

```
<$2_$3>$4</$2_$3>
```

..this gives me almost exactly what I need.

Greetings